# Upload pdf file

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, pdf, file-upload

I want to upload Pdf file into my application

So I have ViewModel (I post only relevant code)

```
public class SubcategoryViewModel
{
    public HttpPostedFileBase PdfFile { get; set; }
    [DisplayName("PDF")]
    public string Pdf { get; set; }
}
```

Controller:

```
 public async Task<string> CreateSubcategory(SubcategoryViewModel model)
    {
              string pdf = null;
            if (model.Pdf != null)
            {
                pdf = Guid.NewGuid().ToString().Substring(0, 13) + "_" + model.File.FileName;
                model.Pdf = pdf;
                var path =    Path.Combine(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/Content/pdf"), pdf);
                model.File.SaveAs(path);
            }

            var subcategory = new Subcategory
            {
                Pdf = pdf,
            };
            db.SubcategoriesList.Add(subcategory);
            await db.SaveChangesAsync();
```

View:

```
@model Models.ViewModels.SubcategoryViewModel
@using (Html.BeginForm("Create", "Subcategory", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" })) 
{
<div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Pdf, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10 legend-size">
            <input type="file" id="file" name="file" />
        </div>
    </div>
```

When I action post I don´t received nothing into model.Pdf, so into   `if (model.Pdf != null)` validation it comes null, and I don´t know why

Anyone have idea why it occurs? Thankyou in advance!

Comment: Unclear what your asking. Your form does not have a form control for property `Pdf` so it will always be `null` when you submit (but its unclear why you would need to post that value anyway)

Comment: I want to upload pdf file from user, and save it into path, then in my index view I want to get it to show it @StephenMuecke

Comment: What does public string Pdf { get; set; } stored? file name?

Comment: Thats fine (I assume you redirecting to the `Index()` method after saving?), but the issue is that you never get to save the file because the code in `if (model.Pdf != null)` is never executed because `model.Pdf` is always `null`

Comment: Best guess is that you want `if (model.PdfFile != null && model.PdfFile .ContentLength > 0) {`

Comment: I think @StephenMuecke is right.

Comment: In addition, your input need to be `<input type="file" name="PdfFile" />` in order to bind to your model.

Comment: I think `<input type="file">` requires `HttpPostedFileBase` which capture uploaded file and insert all contents into the model as byte stream with given file name, to check if file exists use `model.PdfFile != null && model.PdfFile.ContentLength > 0`.

Comment: Yes it works, Thanks! @StephenMuecke

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have 2 main issues. First the name of your file input is `name="file"`, but that does not match the property in your model. It needs to be

```
<input type="file" name="PdfFile" />
```

Second, you never generate an input for property `string Pdf` so in the POST method, it will always be `null` and therefore the code inside your `if (model.Pdf != null)` will never be executed. However, what you really want is to save the file if its not null, so the code needs to be

```
public async Task<string> CreateSubcategory(SubcategoryViewModel model)
{
   string fileName = null;
   if (model.PdfFile != null && model.PdfFile .ContentLength > 0)
   {
       fileName = Guid.NewGuid().ToString().Substring(0, 13) + "_" + model.PdfFile.FileName;
       string path = Path.Combine(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/Content/pdf"), fileName);
       model.PdfFile.SaveAs(path);
    }
    var subcategory = new Subcategory
    {
        Pdf = fileName ,
    };
    db.SubcategoriesList.Add(subcategory);
    await db.SaveChangesAsync();
```

Side note: I would also recommend an additional property in your model for the files display name (i.e. the value of `model.PdfFile.FileName`) so that you can use that in your view rather than displaying the name prefixed with a `Guid` which would have little meaning to the user. Refer [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35904830/asp-net-mvc-upload-image/35906154#35906154) for an example.

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is you are getting null value in `PdfFile` property of your model. This is because you have not given `name` attribute of file upload control same as you property. change `name` attribute of your file upload control to `PdfFile`.

```
<input type="file" id="file" name="PdfFile" />
```